# What is the nicest way to data-bind classes to an input at postlink time?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive wrapping a text input. The input has classes added by ngRequired and ngDisabled when the template is put together. At postlink time, I have additional classes I want to add to the input, but I'm not sure what of the best way to do this.

I used one method but it overwrites angularjs's classes.

```
template: '<input class="{{classes}}" ng-required="true"></input>'
```

There is a second method which adds the classes simply with element.addClass, but this doesn't have data binding.

```
link: function(scope, element) { element.addClass(getGeneratedClasses()) }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T2Zvs/4/

Ng-class doesn't help here, as I want to have a controller using the directive to have control over the classes.

Is there a nice way to data-bind classes from the linking function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your second approach, you could setup a $watch on an function within your (post) link function:

```
 link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
          return {
              hasRequiredClass: element.hasClass('required'),
              hadDisabledClass: element.hasClass('disabled')
          };
      }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if (newVal.hasRequiredClass) {
             //add additional classes
          }
          if (newVal.hasDisabledClass) {
             // add additional classes
          }
      });
 });
```

Comment: I agree that a $watch may be the only way to handle appended classes without overwriting them. I have several directives with appended classes though, and this is a bit wordy so I may just try to avoid it altogether.